# Am/Beim + infinitiv (progressiv) - Difference

Tags: difference, verb-usage

[From WP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am-Progressiv)  I learnt that progressive structures can be translated in German by either *beim* + INF or *am* + INF.

How would you characterise the difference (if any) between these two options? I.e., If I say

> *Ich bin am Lernen*

is it the same as  saying

> *Ich bin beim Lernen*

?

Comment: I'd guess that is a regional difference only - "am" ->north, "beim"->south. Here's a map for "am": http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f10abcd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not standard German. It came up in western German dialects, spoken along the river Rhein, and therefore is called *rheinische Verlaufsform* or, because of the usage of the word *am* to build this progressive form [am-Progressiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am-Progressiv).

This grammatical feature is spreading across a wide range of Germany, but did not cover the whole Germany (as far as I know it is used very rarely in Saxony), and it did not reach Austria. (But it is used in Switzerland.)

The actual status of this feature is: regional colloquial speech. It is not part of the standardized language, but maybe it will be in the future. (Maybe in 50 or 100 years? Maybe even sooner, or even later. Nobody knows.)

Comment: Wirklich? Zumindest [hier](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f18a-b/) und [hier](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f10abcd/) kommt es für mache der untersuchten Verben auch in Österreich vor.

Comment: @Takkat: »Ich bin gerade am überlegen, ob ...« ist tatsächlich auch in Österreich üblich, aber weit davon entfernt als standardsprachlich wahrgenommen zu werden. Bei den anderen untersuchten Verben (»sie ist am Schlafen«, »er ist am Äpfel schälen«) ist mir persönlich diese Form nicht geläufig. Laut deinem Link sollte »ich bin schon am platzen« *manchmal* auch in Ö üblich sein, mir persönlich ist das aber noch nicht untergekommen. Und die Version *»ich bin gerade die Uhr am reparieren«; »er ist die Äpfel am schälen«* ruft vermutlich nicht nur bei mir heftigen Sprachekel hervor.

Comment: Jaaa - auch mir ist ganz blümerant, wenn ich das höre. Ich kann aber beim besten Willen keine Regel finden, nach der man entweder *am* oder *beim* oder gar *im* nimmt... nur, dass ich das jeweils andere als falsch empfinde.

Comment: Ich bin Frankfurter, ich kenne die Form, habe aber den Verdacht, dass ich das vor allem vom Siegerländer Platt kenne (da kommt mein Vater her). "Ech sinn am ääwe" ("ich bin am Arbeiten") macht für mich gefühlt mehr Sinn im Sejerlänner Platt als im Frankfurter Hessisch ("Isch bin am abbeidde"?). Wenn ich hochdeutsch spreche, vermeide ich das, denn dann klingt es falsch. Meine persönliche Empfehlung daher: im Hochdeutschen vermeiden - und umgangssprachlich "am", nicht "beim".

Comment: Waouw... as a beginning German learner I am bit lost by this discussion... interesting nevertheless ;). @JimiJackson should I infer that grammar varies across dialects?

Comment: @hartmut there are sometimes (usually minor) grammatical anomalies in dialects, but I think that's true for dialects in all languages. Take for example some English dialects using double negative or "he don't". The fact that it's also referred to as "rheinische Verlaufsform" (from the river Rhine) already suggests it's dialectal. What I find fascinating about it is the similarity to the English progressive form. In German, instead of a progressive form you usually use the simple form + modifier, as in "Ich arbeite gerade" for "I am working". This form however is literally "I am at working".

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Is this something that would be colloquially written in German as opposed to using the Absentive? For instance, if I wanted to say "I was shopping", spoken I could say "Ich war einkaufen", however when written should I say "Ich war beim Einkaufen", right?

Comment: @BlauKakapoW: *»Ich war einkaufen.«* is an absolutely correct Standard-German construction, but it has nothing to do with continuous or progressive forms. The sentence *»Ich war beim Einkaufen.«* is only then correct German, if *»Einkaufen«* is the name of a shop, which is very unlikely. Otherwise it is wrong. (Words with an uppercase first letter are nouns, like names.) Maybe there are some regions, where *»Ich war beim einkaufen.«* (note the lowercase version indicating a non-noun word, like a verb) is used in colloquial speech. But this is incorrect in Standard German.

Comment: That is good to know as most of the info covering "am/beim infinitive" does not specify if it is commonly accepted as part of the language. The reason I asked is that I have seen the progressive form online, although I can't say I've ever seen it in a book. I know I've seen it in news articles, but again, it's not very common.

Comment: @BlauKakapoW: Whether it is commonly accepted as part of the language or not is exactly what the last paragraph of my answer is about: *»The actual status of this feature is: regional colloquial speech. It is not part of the standardized language, but maybe it will be in the future.«*